# How to connect Xcode and iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have completed my first app.  iTunes Connect is waiting for its upload and has designated the app as “Waiting for Upload”.  I started the process of archiving.  When complete, I clicked the Validate button and received this: “No identities available for signing”.   I tried to download identities and received the warning sign and message “ An administrator must request identities before they can be downloaded”.

The validation provided the following warning “warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)”.

I have researched these messages through the forum and though there are several sightings, I cannot for the life of me figure out what to do.  I assume there is some sort of breakdown in communication between Xcode and iTunes Connect.    My roles in iTunes connect are “admin” and “legal”.    I am a team of one.   Assistance would be greatly appreciated, for I have come far and find defeat near at hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process is a nightmare the first time you do it.
I think the most important thing is the certificates and code signing, the rest is not too hard.

I recommend you take these steps:

1. Log in to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action and you will have to create 2 certificates (1 for development & 1 for distribution) and 2 provisioning profiles(1 for development & 1 for distribution).

   The certificates are a bit harder to make than the provisioning profiles because it involves making another certificate from your MAC's keychain, but don't worry, apple tells you how this is done here:
    https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateLanding.action
2. After you have made all 2 certificates and 2 provisioning profiles, you will need to download them and double click on each one so that Xcode and Kaychain can read them.

   Now this is the most important thing... you MUST set your app's code signing to match with the new  2 Provisioning Profiles that you just created.

   Both your project and your target's code signing MUST be set to match with these provisioning profiles. The 'debug' code signing should be set with the 'development' provisioning profile, and the 'release' code signing must be set with the 'distribution' provisioning profile.

Here are 2 screenshots, one of the code signing for the app's target, and one of the code signing for the app's project:
[image: code signing for Target]

[image: code signing for Project]

Once you have done that (assuming that you have set up your app Bundle ID in Xcode to match the app id that you used to create the provisioning profiles), all you will need to do now is archive it and attempt to once again upload it to itunesconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial, it covers it all from scratch.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2

and this one

http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/2012/how-to-publish-your-app-on-the-app-store/

Comment: I have been through this document before.  I did learn a little, but still no idea on how to make the link.  I can see now that the 10 alphanumeric code for my userid on XCode is different than the 10 digit code i have in iTunes connect.  Both codes are found in XCode, but one of them is marked as "Identities without Provisioning Profiles".  This is way beyond my pay-grade and am still stuck.  thanks

Comment: I believe xcode 5 will all this so much easier. For a full run down try Lynda.com and Distributing iOS Applications Through the App Store.