# Problems with uploading an app to the app store

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, provisioning-profile

I am trying to upload my app to the app store, and have been following the tutorial on the developer website. I have got my distribution certificate and have created a distribution provisioning profile, but I can seem to put it into Xcode? If I just click on the .mobileprovision file in finder, it opens Xcode and does nothing. If I go into the organizer, and click on provisioning profiles under my phone, it won't allow me to add the file. When I manually drag the file in, it tells me it could not be installed on my phone because it's not included in the profile. I don't know whether I want it installed on my phone or what to do. I just want to put it on the App Store!

Comment: Everything is on Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission.html

Comment: check my comments on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796772/how-to-connect-xcode-and-itunes-connect/18801801#18801801 has 2 really good examples that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the .mobileprovision file in finder, it opens Xcode and it DOES something. It imports that provisioning file. If you have all other certificates also installed, you don't have to manually install the provisioning profile in your phone. When you make a build using Xcode provisioning profile should automatically get installed in your phone.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to distinguish different types of provision profiles.

1. Development Provision Profile - you need this profile for testing and debugging application on your device. 
   Your device UDID should be added to this provision profile.
   You can do this with the Apple Developer Member Center.
2. Ad Hoc Provision profile - usually used for beta-testing via Testflight or Fabric.
   You cannot debug app with this profile because it is signed with distribution certificate.
3. Distribution provision profile - used for distributing your app through AppStore.

Your next steps:

1. Check what provision profiles you have. You can download or refresh them through Xcode using Preferences/Accounts.
2. If you want to test app on your devices make sure your UDID has been added to Development Provision Profile.
3. If you want to upload app for distribution create Distribution Provision Profile in Apple Developer Member Center.

If you want to check what profiles and certificates are currently used for your app you need to check Xcode/Your_Target/BuildSettings/Signing